# How to simplify my code

Tags: group-by, subquery, union

I was asked to show information for every month about the top N counted records from a month, I mean, I need to count a field, select the top 5 and bind with every month/year. My current code is as follows:

```
( 
select calle1, count(calle1), year(fecha_registro), MONTH(fecha_registro) from dbo_accidentes1 
where year(fecha_registro)=2013 and MONTH(fecha_registro)=1 
GROUP BY calle1 
order by count(calle1) desc LIMIT 6 
) 
UNION 
( 
select calle1, count(calle1), year(fecha_registro), MONTH(fecha_registro) from dbo_accidentes1 
where year(fecha_registro)=2013 and MONTH(fecha_registro)=2 
GROUP BY calle1 
order by count(calle1) desc LIMIT 6 
) 
UNION 
( 
select calle1, count(calle1), year(fecha_registro), MONTH(fecha_registro) from dbo_accidentes1 
where year(fecha_registro)=2013 and MONTH(fecha_registro)=3 
GROUP BY calle1 
order by count(calle1) desc LIMIT 6 
) 
UNION 
( 
select calle1, count(calle1), year(fecha_registro), MONTH(fecha_registro) from dbo_accidentes1 
where year(fecha_registro)=2013 and MONTH(fecha_registro)=4 
GROUP BY calle1 
order by count(calle1) desc LIMIT 6 
) 
UNION 
( 
select calle1, count(calle1), year(fecha_registro), MONTH(fecha_registro) from dbo_accidentes1 
where year(fecha_registro)=2013 and MONTH(fecha_registro)=5 
GROUP BY calle1 
order by count(calle1) desc LIMIT 6 
) 
UNION 
( 
select calle1, count(calle1), year(fecha_registro), MONTH(fecha_registro) from dbo_accidentes1 
where year(fecha_registro)=2013 and MONTH(fecha_registro)=6 
GROUP BY calle1 
order by count(calle1) desc LIMIT 6 
)
```

It shows somethng like this:

https://fbcdn-sphotos-a-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn2/q71/s720x720/1468653_659639267414302_124224845_n.jpg

The code is big as hell, but does the work. I was wondering if there is any way to reduce it, because I think I would work with other range of months in the future. I tried a lot with joins, subqueries, but none of them are working for me, I can't retrieve the top 5 records from an inner query or a second table in a join.

Comment: what RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, in case your RDBMS support window function:

```
with t as 
(select calle1, count(calle1) as count_acc, year(fecha_registro) as year_acc, MONTH(fecha_registro) as Month_acc 
from dbo_accidentes1 
GROUP BY calle1, year(fecha_registro),MONTH(fecha_registro) ), 
t2 as
(select  calle1, count_acc, year_acc, Month_acc,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY calle1 ORDER BY count_acc desc) as rank)
select *
from t2
where rank <= 6
```